# failing when trying to push to my remote git repository

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

i'm new use of VSCode. I'm trying to push my commits to remote repo, i'm getting credentials prompt, but i getting following output:

```
remote: Anonymous access to myname/myrepo.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myname/myrepo.git/'
git fetch
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: On what platform you're running VSCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many people having this problem. I know it has been reported for a couple of times here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List
It seems those tickets are not available on public. File a new bug. Hopefully they are going to fix it until the next release.

Comment: As a temporary work around, you can replace `https://github.com/myname/myrepo.git/` with `git@github.com:myname/myrepo.git`.  This will use SSH instead of HTTPS.  You will need a private key on your computer that matches a public key in your GitHub account.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a problem where I was receiving a similar error, and I found these articles resourceful to fix this issue.

Potential reasons for problem:

1. Windows Credentials doesn't have the right Github credentials

[Adding Git credentials on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878457/adding-git-credentials-on-windows)

2. Github deprecated password authentication and you now have to use Personal Access Token when pushing

https://techglimpse.com/git-push-github-token-based-passwordless/

Hope this is helpful to anyone else that comes across this post.