# Wincred not working properly with Git Bash(Git for Windows) when executing certain commands like "prune"

Tags: git, git-bash, git-for-windows, advapi32, credential-manager

I have setup GitforWindows in my Windows 7 64Bit pretty well with Credential manager as "Wincred".

Yet when I run some commands like `git remote prune origin` in GitBash, it gives following error in console, though runs the command:

```
Failed to load advapi32.dll
```

Why is that ? If there is something need to be done with Credential manager settings, then I need full explanation of how to do those settings and what each setting means.

**Note:** This problem I have only with some commands, other commands are running just fine without any errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), make sure to set your credential helper to manager, not WinCred (which was obsoleted some times ago)

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

That will use the [GCM-core (Git-Credential-Manager-Core)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows).

As [mentioned here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64/tree/master/mingw64/doc/git-credential-manager):

> It's the successor to the Windows Credential Store for [Git (`git-credential-winstore`)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150325080236/http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/), **which is no longer maintained**.
>
> Compared to Git's built-in credential storage for Windows (`wincred`), which provides single-factor authentication support working on any HTTP enabled Git repository, GCM provides multi-factor authentication support for Azure DevOps, Team Foundation Server, GitHub, and Bitbucket.

Updte 2021: [GCM-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) is now the up-to-date solution, cross-platform Windows-Linux-Mac.

Update 2022:

It has been replaced by [GCM](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (Git Credential Manager), and [after Git 2.38.1, is called `manager` (no longer "`manager-core`")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309).

If you have upgraded [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), you can safely change your credential helper to manager.

```bash
# up to Git 2.38.1 on Windows
git config --global credential.helper manager-core

# Git 2.39+
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan True. I have updated the answer accordingly: GCM-Core is the current solution.