# Setup Windows credential manager and it to push to repo

Tags: git

I am trying to setup a new Windows server to run a scheduled task, which will push files into a repo (on my internal GitLab server). I have version 2.22.0 and am running the following command:

```
git.exe push origin master
```

Every time, I get prompted for git@git.domain.com's password.

I ran:

```
git config --global -e
```

and saved:

```
[credential]
        helper = wincred
[credentials]
        helper = wincred
```

Then I put a generic credential with the address "git.domain.com" (and the service account's username and password) into the Windows credential manger, but I still get prompted.

What part am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[`wincred` is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184233/6309).

You should try:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Make sure that there is no credentials entry in your `</repo>/.git/config` local git configuration.

Then try again.