# Error fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no Unix socket support

Tags: git, github

I'm having an app and trying to push it to a Private rep but not sure why I'm getting this error: Code didn't show up on GitHub

```
>git push -u origin main
    fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support
    Everything up-to-date
    Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+credential-cache+unavailable%3B+no+unix+socket+support

Comment: I know that this question is closed and marked as duplicate and that there is redirection on another question... BUT: I just had the same problem and I tried some advices...nothing worked. 
Then I found this thread: 
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Error-Logon-failed-use-ctrl-c-to-cancel-basic-credential-prompt/qaq-p/1540433 .
There is simpe solution in four steps:
1. Go to Tools in Sourcetree > Options >Authentication
2. Delete account from there.
3. Then click On Add button and refresh OAuth Token 
4. After success ... Get On Your Work

Comment: Reported bug https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3892

Comment: **Workaround**: install and configure [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager#windows) `git-credential-manager-core --configure`. The default credential store [Windows Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md#windows-credential-manager) `git config --global credential.credentialStore wincredman` works very well.

Comment: I faced this problem when trying to clone LFS files. Didn't face this issue when cloning repos without LFS files.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Somewhere in your configuration, you have a credential helper set to `cache` and on your system you don't have Unix socket support, almost certainly because your system is Windows.  (If you are on a Unix system, your system is seriously misconfigured.)

You should run `git config -l --show-origin` to find out where you've set the `credential.helper` option to `cache` and remove that entry, since the credential helper won't work in your version of Git.

Note that newer versions of Windows 10 do offer Unix sockets, but by default Git is not compiled to use them on Windows.

---

That starts to change with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), which adjusts `credential-cache` helper to Windows.

See [commit bb390b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb390b1f49406d967e8bf3401337cf1d9535f820), [commit 245670c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/245670cd46c4713818b5fbca2c084ce2e19f4ed8), [commit 0fdcfa2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fdcfa2f9f59a8bf4202ac3933991f42a4ac1393) (14 Sep 2021) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c2e7990](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2e799012b3657f4f91560d299b5606c297e7cf7), 23 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-compat-util`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb390b1f49406d967e8bf3401337cf1d9535f820): include declaration for unix sockets in windows
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>

> Available since Windows 10 release 1803 and Windows Server 2019.
>
> `NO_UNIX_SOCKETS` is still the default for Windows builds, as they need to keep backward compatibility with releases up to Windows 7, but allow including the header otherwise.

Comment: Thank you mate , I found this one : file:C:/Users/abc/.gitconfig    credential.helper=cache  
But how can I remove the entry

Comment: Righ, OS is Windows

Comment: Edit it with a text editor and remove the `helper = cache` line.  Vim, VS Code, nano, whatever you like.  Any text editor is fine.

Comment: Ok , Mate. Really appreciate it. I deleted the git and initialized it again . So grateful

Comment: Adding to this answer since it helped my case - you could directly replace the cache in `helper = cache` to `helper = wincred` in the .gitconfig file. Another way of doing it is from the Git Bash, `git config --global credential.helper wincred` after deleting the credential.helper cache

Comment: @RandomRushGirl `wincred`? But [`wincred` is obsolete for years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184233/6309): it should be `manager` now.

Comment: @VonC oh is it? it seemed to be what fixed my problem with git pull and push. i think there is something else going on in the background that i’m not aware of yet then 

Comment: @RandomRushGirl What version of Git are you using? (`git --version`)

Comment: @VonC It is at 2.42. I'm curious why wincred solved my problem. Any info is appreciated :)

Comment: @RandomRushGirl For now, `git-credential-manager.exe` is still part of the Git for Windows release. I would still advise you to switch to manager though.

Answer (score 27):

To delete the entry for helper, do:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: I'd like to send much appreciated for this tip. Great find and very helpful. Thanks.