# SourceTree issue - Cannot spawn C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Currently, I'm unable to clone my repository from Bitbucket. I get this error
"This is not avalid source path/URL"
Details button when clicked I get this Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:abc/xxx.git
Output:
Error: error: cannot spawn C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
Please advise as the solution on this page did not work for me --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574267/cannot-spawn-ssh-when-connecting-to-github-but-ssh-t-gitgithub-com-works

FYI: I have Windows 10 OS

Thanks

Tried this below
["Cannot spawn ssh" when connecting to Github, but ssh -T git@github.com works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574267/cannot-spawn-ssh-when-connecting-to-github-but-ssh-t-gitgithub-com-works)

Tried removing the cache for credential_helper from this page [Error fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no Unix socket support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951554/error-fatal-credential-cache-unavailable-no-unix-socket-support)

Tried uninstalling and re-installing sourcetree

None of these have helped me

Comment: I get 2 paths when I execute this cmd on Git Bash...$ where ssh
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe Is this causing an issue by any chance?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was able to clone repo from BitBucket using Clone button from "SourceTree" tool. When I attempt to do this, it says "This is not a valid URL". Kindly let me know why this error pops up all of a sudden when no changes are made to the private/public keys. It complains on C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe not found but I can see this in my explorer in this path. I'm unable to make out what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I read a post somewhere that said Windows translate `c:\Windows\System32` to `c:\Windows\SysWOW64`, and that could be the reason OpenSSH wasn't found.

So, I opened up command prompt in Administrator mode, changed to the SysWOW64 directory, and created a symbolic link using mklink command:

```
cd c:\Windows\SysWOW64
mklink /d OpenSSH c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
```

And now it seems to work.